# generate 6 digit number which will expire after 5 second

Tags: c#, timestamp

Based on current date and time, can i generate 6 digit number? One person said me to use timestamp. Please guide me how to generate 6 digit number based on current time stamp. I need to generate this in such way later I can check the number was generate before 5 second or not. I need to know what logic should I use to reverse logic to find out when the number was generated. Please help with sample code.

Which crypto technique i can use to generate digit if i input current date like `DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff")` ?.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate 6 digit random number based on current date & time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698013/how-to-generate-6-digit-random-number-based-on-current-date-time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
public static int GetTimestamp()
{
    // 10m ticks in a second, so 50m in 5 seconds
    const int ticksIn5Seconds = 50000000;
    return (int)((DateTime.Now.Ticks / ticksIn5Seconds) % 1000000);
}
```

This gets a number with one to six digits, which changes every five seconds.

**Edit:**

If course, this is not cryptographically secure: if you observe one number then you know what later ones are going to be (because they just increase by 1 each time). If unpredictability is a requirement, you need a different approach.

Comment: ur code looks promising but i could not understand the calculation. why should i divide DateTime.Now.Ticks by 50000000 and remainder divide by 1000000. would u mind to explain this calculation in detail. thanks for ur code.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Ticks` is a very large number, increasing at the rate of 10,000,000 every second. The (integer) division by 50,000,000 gives a number that increases by 1 every five seconds. Finally, the `% 1000000` causes this result to wrap round to 0 if it exceeds 999,999, so you never have more than six digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Get currect tick count
  string sTicks = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString(); 
  // get 5 least-significat digits
  string sNum = sTicks.Substring(sTicks.Length - 5, 5);
```

You need to take into consideration that after 100000 ticks, there's a somewhat **high probability** that you`ll get the same numbers again.

There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.

Comment: so how to check the number was generated before 5 sec or not...what logic i need to use...plzz come with sample code.