# How to convert datetime to timestamp using C#/.NET (ignoring current timezone)

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

How do I convert datetime to timestamp using C# .NET (ignoring the current timezone)?

I am using the below code:

```
private long ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    long epoch = (value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
    return epoch;
}
```

But it returns the timestamp value according to the current time zone & and I need the result without using the current timezone.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/892074/function-that-creates-a-timestamp-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 77):

At the moment you're calling `ToUniversalTime()` - just get rid of that:

```
private long ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    long epoch = (value.Ticks - 621355968000000000) / 10000000;
    return epoch;
}
```

Alternatively, and rather more readably IMO:

```
private static readonly DateTime Epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
...

private static long ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    TimeSpan elapsedTime = value - Epoch;
    return (long) elapsedTime.TotalSeconds;
}
```

EDIT: As noted in the comments, the `Kind` of the `DateTime` you pass in isn't taken into account when you perform subtraction. You should really pass in a value with a `Kind` of `Utc` for this to work. Unfortunately, `DateTime` is a bit broken in this respect - see [my blog post](https://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) (a rant about `DateTime`) for more details.

You might want to use my [Noda Time](https://github.com/nodatime/nodatime) date/time API instead which makes everything rather clearer, IMO.

Comment: Prefer the second one too. The Op didn't say what he wanted it for but is the output equatable to what SqlServer would generate when creating a timestamp if you converted it to binary? Also why the cast to long, haven't fired up VS to check but does TotalSeconds not return a long?

Comment: @Bronumski: No, it returns a `double`. I don't know whether it's comparable, I'm afraid - I don't know what SQL Server does.

Comment: SQL Server has 0 = 1900-01-01 00:00:00.000, according to me lame test of creating a datetime and stuffing numbers into it.  Adding 1 adds 1 day.  Adding 0.5 adds 12 hours.  The value can be less than 0 for years before 1900.

Comment: @Brian: Right, in that case you'd need to tweak it - use a different epoch, and take TotalDays instead.

Comment: @JonSkeet we really need to use `new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc)` to get `Epoch` correctly as DateTime wothout a `Kind` corresponds to user local `TimeZone`

Comment: @A rash: Yes, that's better - although it's still not quite enough, as the kind isn't taken into account when subtracting. Also, an unspecified kind isn't the same as local - it's all a bit nuts. My Noda Time library deals with this more clearly, IMO :)

Comment: @ArashMilani - You might be able to adjust the above code to work with `Local` kinds, but there's no way to make it work with `Unspecified` kind since it doesn't know anything about how it relates to UTC.  And since `Local` only comes from `DateTime.Now`, where you could have just used `DateTime.UtcNow`, then there really isn't any benefit to doing this with other kinds than `Utc`.  I can attest to NodaTime being a much better solution.  See also [this blog post](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/) I wrote.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not exactly sure what it is that you want. Do you want a TimeStamp? Then you can do something simple like:

```
TimeStamp ts = TimeStamp.FromTicks(value.ToUniversalTime().Ticks);
```

Since you named a variable epoch, do you want the Unix time equivalent of your date?

```
DateTime unixStart = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1), DateTimeKind.Utc);
long epoch = (long)Math.Floor((value.ToUniversalTime() - unixStart).TotalSeconds);
```

Comment: DateTime unixStart = DateTime.SpecifyKind(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1), DateTimeKind.Utc);
long epoch = (long)Math.Floor((value.ToUniversalTime() - unixStart).TotalSeconds);

this also returns the same result as that of my code...

Comment: Then I don't understand what's wrong with your code. I use this in production code to get the Unix timestamp (which is UTC) and as far as I know it works. No matter which timezone the `value` is in, I always get the correct corresponding UTC time.

Comment: If you just want the epoch time, corresponding to the same timezone as the original value, then the code posted by Jon Skeet is correct.

Answer (score 2):

Find timestamp from DateTime:

```
private long ConvertToTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    TimeZoneInfo NYTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
    DateTime NyTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(value, NYTimeZone);
    TimeZone localZone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;
    System.Globalization.DaylightTime dst = localZone.GetDaylightChanges(NyTime.Year);
    NyTime = NyTime.AddHours(-1);
    DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime();
    TimeSpan span = (NyTime - epoch);
    return (long)Convert.ToDouble(span.TotalSeconds);
}
```

Comment: you did not use dst at all!

Answer (score 1):

JonSkeet has a good answer but as an alternative if you wanted to keep the result more portable you could convert the date into an [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format which could then be read into most other frameworks but this may fall outside your requirements.

```
value.ToUniversalTime().ToString("O");
```