# How to convert time only using DateTime.Parse?

Tags: c#

I have a string variable with it's value formatted to look like "1:23:45 AM"
I need to convert that into a DateTime variable for time without a date component.
I am receiving an "Unhandled exception" error that is being caused by the formatting.  If I remove the "AM", it works fine but the "AM/PM" component is needed for what I am trying to do.
I am currently using the following code to attempt this...

"temp" is the name of the variable I am using until I come up with a more meaningful variable name...

```
public string PlusMinus12(string hour, string minute, string second, string ampm)
    {
        string PlusMinus;
        int rndmTmp1 = Random1();
        int rndmTmp2 = Random2();

        if (rndmTmp1 == 0)
        {
            PlusMinus = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + ": " + ampm;
            return PlusMinus;
        }
        else if (rndmTmp1 == 1)
        {
            string temp = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second +": " + ampm;
            **DateTime subtract = DateTime.Parse(temp);**
            subtract.AddSeconds(-rndmTmp2);
            PlusMinus = subtract.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
            return PlusMinus;
        }
        else
        {
```

DateTime subtract = DateTime.Parse(temp); is the line causing the error

The error is:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Most of the information I have found so far on this topic include solutions that depend on the existence of the Date component, which I am not using.

Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Can you show what `temp` has for a value?  I'm not getting any exception running your code.  You need to show *all* your *relevant* code and indicate where the exception is occurring.  Also, what is the actual error message?

Comment: Are you sure the temp string is the format you expect?  It's working for me also.

Comment: Maybe this is your answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814060/how-to-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-using-c-net-ignoring-current-timezone On another note, I tried it your code converting it to string format with no problem. I would double check the format.

Comment: I have updated the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is this

```
PlusMinus = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + ": " + ampm;
```

Change it to

`PlusMinus = Int32.Parse(hour).ToString("00") + ":" + Int32.Parse(minute).ToString("00") + ":" + second.ToString("00") + " " + ampm`;

A little convoluted since strings are passed in as input.  No colon after the seconds and [zero pad the numbers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8(v=vs.110).aspx).  Also, since they are input variables, at some point you should verify that they are between 0-59.

Comment: Thank you!  The issue was that I am going blind and did not even see the colon after the seconds...

Answer (score 3):

You should try parsing it using [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) using a custom format from here: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in returning the time part, add a extra variable that holds the date part and append it to the front of temp when you parse it? 
like:

```
string tempDate = "2008-05-01 "
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
        string timeString = "1:23:45 AM";
        string format = "h:mm:ss tt";
        CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        try
        {
            DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(timeString, format, provider);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", timeString, result.ToString());
        }
        catch (FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", timeString);
        }
```

Probably your issue is with a particular time.

UPDATE: You need to check you are passing minutes and seconds to this function with a 0 for values like 1-2..9. Because standard provider will not accept a string like '1:1:2 AM'.

Answer (score 0):

public string PlusMinus12(string hour, string minute, string second, string ampm)
    {
        string PlusMinus;
        int rndmTmp1 = Random1();
        int rndmTmp2 = Random2();

```
    if (rndmTmp1 == 0)
    {
        PlusMinus = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + ": " + ampm;
        return PlusMinus;
    }
    else if (rndmTmp1 == 1)
    {
        string temp = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second +": " + ampm;
        DateTime subtract = DateTime.Parse("2000-01-01 " + temp);
        subtract.AddSeconds(-rndmTmp2);
        PlusMinus = subtract.ToString("h:mm:ss tt");
        return PlusMinus;
    }
    else
    {
```