# I Want Convert My Datetime to TimeStamp C#?

Tags: c#

I want to convert my datetime in C# (e.g. `2009-06-22 16:35:16.000`) to something like this `1196550000000`. I tried the following method but it fails.

```
public static double GetTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    long ticks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - DateTime.Parse(value.ToString()).Ticks;
    ticks /= 10000000; //Convert windows ticks to seconds
    Int64 timestamp = ticks;
    return timestamp;
}
```

Comment: `DateTime.Parse(value.ToString()).Ticks` equals `value.Ticks` in case of successful parse

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert datetime to timestamp using C#/.NET (ignoring current timezone)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814060/how-to-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-using-c-net-ignoring-current-timezone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need to `ToString()` and Reparse the `DateTime`. If you want just the `Date` you can use the `DateTime.Date` property.

Then, this should be simple enough (using `DateTime.Now` as a reference point):

```
public static double GetTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
    return new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - value.Ticks).TotalSeconds;
}
```

In case the parsing you did in your question did refer to extracting the date from the `DateTime`, you can use the following:

```
public static double GetTimestamp(DateTime value)
{
     return new TimeSpan(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks - value.Date.Ticks).TotalSeconds;
}
```

EDIT : You appear to want some kind of posix time conversion which can be achieved like this :

```
private static readonly DateTime POSIXRoot = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
public static double GetPosixSeconds(DateTime value)
{
    return (value - POSIXRoot).TotalSeconds;
}

public static DateTime GetDateTime(double posixSeconds) {
    return POSIXRoot.AddSeconds(posixSeconds);
}
```

Comment: i used this method to make sure of covering

Comment: <!-- language: c# -->public static DateTime RetunValuedate(double Date) { var dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds(Math.Round(Date / 1000d)).ToLocalTime(); DateTime h = dt; return h; }>`

Comment: i use some method to make sure the correct number but i don't know how i can highlight it ?

Comment: So you are trying to get some kind of POSIX time from it ? You just have to replace the DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks by the posix root, see my edit.

Comment: i have chart using this number  if you use this (1196463600000) on my method it will return  (12/1/2007) it is the only one method return the chart Date

Comment: it is long number your method use int32 only