# DateTime sql server vs. System.DateTime

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a stored procedure which input is from the type `datetime`. i.e. I transfer the input 
`2014-01-13T16:55:03.370` ,while running the stored procedure from the sql server.

Now I want to execute a stored procedure from the application.So I tried to use parameter having `System.DateTime` type.Looks like it is not corresponds to `sql datetime`.
Which type should I use for that?

UPD.
I didn`t get the answer for my question. So I`ll try to make my question more clear.
In SQL SErver database tables the values of the type datetime are saved.I am writing a stored procedure which looks for this values .I mean I need to get a parameter from the user of the for yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss:.mmmm

Comment: Show your code & exception you are getting

Comment: Sure - the .NET `DateTime` corresponds to the SQL Server `DATETIME`. The only "issue" you might run into is a question of **range** - .NET goes from `01-01-0001` to `31-12-9999` while SQL Server's `DATETIME` start at year 1753 (`DATE` or `DATETIME2` in SQL Server **2008** and newer don't have that limit anymore)

Answer (score 1):

from MSDN:

GetDate() is a inbuilt function in sql, for c# you can use follwing:

```
  DateTime CurrentDate;
  CurrentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
```

I guess you can pass this variable through to the procedure call parameters?

or, search the site again and read: [Function that creates a timestamp in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892074/function-that-creates-a-timestamp-in-c-sharp)

Comment: You should **never** need to convert a `DateTime` to a string if the very next operation you're going to perform is to convert it back into a `DateTime`. You code looks like it's trying to remove the time portion from `DateTime.Now` - something more easily achieved with `DateTime.Now.Date`

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx) you can find samples on data time conversions between SQL and C#, depending 
on the date data types you use