# C# alternative to Node.js package 'present'

Tags: c#, node.js

I have a Node.js app. That app uses the [present package](https://github.com/beardtree/present). This package provides high resolution timestamps. These timestamps are represented as doubles. I need to figure out how to get a high resolution timestamp in C#.

How do I get a high resolution timestamp (up to microsecond precision) in C#?

Thank you!

Comment: this might be useful to you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class provides access to time with the highest resolution available. You will need to combine calls to Elapsed with single  call to [`DateTime.UtcNow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.utcnow(v=vs.110).aspx) if you need timestamps similar to JavaScript Date.now.

If you are fine with just `DateTime` resolution - check out [Function that creates a timestamp in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892074/function-that-creates-a-timestamp-in-c-sharp) - covers many options, including using `DateTime` and integer counter to provide timestamps that are sortable and guaranteed to be unique in the single process.

Note: as with most timestamps you can't relay on timestamps created on different machines/process for ordering entries/logs, so picking higher resolution timestamps over simply unique once may not give much benefits.