# Add X days to timestamp

Tags: c#, timestamp

the title might be a bit confusing but I had no plan how to name it. I am programming an emulator for a game and the game is using Timestamp for the premium time calculation.

What I need is a function to get the current timestamp and then a function that adds x days to it, so for example:

```
int daysToAdd = 10;
long Timestamp_normal = GetTimestamp();
long newTimestamp = AddDays(Timestamp_normal, daysToAdd);
```

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DateTime to do the calculations and convert that to a timestamp:

```
var startDate = DateTime.Now;
long startTimeStamp = startDate.ToTimeStamp();

var endDate = startDate.AddDays(1);
long endTimeStamp = endDate.ToTimeStamp();
```

There are various way to make a "timestamp" from a DateTime (depending on your definition of timestamp), so pick any that works and move that to a DateTime extension method as demonstrated above:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
    public static long ToTimeStamp(this DateTime input)
    {
        // your implementation here
    }
}
```

For implementations see [Function that creates a timestamp in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/892074/function-that-creates-a-timestamp-in-c-sharp?lq=1), [How to convert datetime to timestamp using C#/.NET (ignoring current timezone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814060/how-to-convert-datetime-to-timestamp-using-c-netignoring-current-timezone), [How to get the unix timestamp in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17632584/how-to-get-the-unix-timestamp-in-c-sharp), and so on.

Comment: .ToTimeStamp seems to be not existing.

Comment: No, that's an extension method I made up. It's in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you just wanted to get the `Ticks` for that particular day

```
long ts1 = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10).Ticks;
```

Comment: The question is not _"How to make a timestamp from a DateTime"_, and that question has been answered plenty of times before (see three links in my answer).

Comment: @CodeCaster, didn't the question says *a function to get the current timestamp and then a function that adds x days to it*? I didn't see a need for a specific function though.